# How to add cards with different layouts using CardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardslib

How can I add cards with different layouts using `CardArrayRecyclerViewAdapter`. Specifically I am interested in having a header followed by cards with different layouts?

Answer (score 0):

The adapters for `RecyclerView` have a method called `getItemViewType()`.
That type is passed to 'onCreateViewHolder()' so you can inflate different layouts.

So you only need to override `getItemViewType()` and return different values depending on each layout you want to inflate

Comment: In `onCreateViewHolder` the condition `this.mRowLayoutIds != null && this.mRowLayoutIds.length != 0` is considered. If condition is false, `BaseRecyclerViewAdapter` will inflate a base card layout for each row otherwise it will inflate a card layout based on the id in `mRowLayoutIds[viewType]`. Is my statement correct?